# Add a total to SUM the pivoted columns in a cross-tab query

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have made a cross-tab query that lists the total stock on each of the location for a particular item.

```
 WITH PIVOT_DATA AS (
   SELECT A.ITEM, A.LOC, A.STOCK_ON_HAND, B.ITEM_DESC
   FROM   ITEM_LOC_SOH A, ITEM_MASTER B
   WHERE A.ITEM = B.ITEM
 )
 SELECT *
   FROM   pivot_data
   PIVOT (
     SUM( nvl(STOCK_ON_HAND,0) )        --<-- pivot_clause
     FOR LOC          --<-- pivot_for_clause
     IN  (
       15002 J12,
       16009 SPR,
       15008 J16,
       12002 JS1
     )   --<-- pivot_in_clause
 );
```

the result shows

```
ITEM  ITEM_DESC J12 SPR J16 JS1 
222   desc_xxx   2   4   5   6
```

I want a total to be added at the very end like:

```
ITEM  ITEM_DESC J12 SPR J16 JS1 Total 
222   desc_xxx   2   4   5   6   17
```

what do I add in the query?

NEW CODE:

```
WITH PIVOT_DATA AS 
(
SELECT A.ITEM, A.LOC, A.STOCK_ON_HAND, B.ITEM_DESC,IL.UNIT_RETAIL, B.BRAND_NAME, DECODE(B.STATUS, 'A', 'ACTIVE'), D.DEPT_NAME DEPARTEMENT, C.CLASS_NAME CLASS
FROM  ITEM_LOC_SOH A, ITEM_MASTER B, DEPS D, CLASS C, ITEM_LOC IL
WHERE A.ITEM = B.ITEM AND IL.ITEM = A.ITEM AND IL.ITEM = B.ITEM 
AND B.DEPT = D.DEPT AND B.DEPT = C.DEPT AND B.CLASS = C.CLASS AND D.DEPT = C.DEPT
AND A.ITEM = '00090909'

    UNION

    -- Insert "Totals" rows into the Cte
SELECT A.ITEM, 9999 AS Loc, SUM(A.STOCK_ON_HAND) AS STOCK_ON_HAND, B.ITEM_DESC,
il.unit_retail, B.BRAND_NAME, DECODE(B.STATUS, 'A', 'ACTIVE'), D.DEPT_NAME DEPARTEMENT
, C.CLASS_NAME CLASS
FROM   ITEM_LOC_SOH A, ITEM_MASTER B, DEPS D, CLASS C, ITEM_LOC IL
WHERE A.ITEM = B.ITEM AND IL.ITEM = A.ITEM AND IL.ITEM = B.ITEM AND A.ITEM = '00090909'
AND B.DEPT = D.DEPT AND B.DEPT = C.DEPT AND B.CLASS = C.CLASS AND D.DEPT = C.DEPT
GROUP BY A.ITEM, B.ITEM_DESC, IL.UNIT_RETAIL, B.BRAND_NAME, DECODE(B.STATUS, 'A', 'ACTIVE'), D.DEPT_NAME, C.CLASS_NAME
)
SELECT x.*
FROM   pivot_data
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(STOCK_ON_HAND)
    FOR LOC
    IN  
    (
       15002 J12,
       16009 SPR,
       15008 J16,
       12002 JS1,
       9999 Total
    )
 ) x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this

- Simply project the total as a new column by explicitly summing up the resulting PIVOT columns:

```
WITH PIVOT_DATA AS 
(
    SELECT A.ITEM, A.LOC, A.STOCK_ON_HAND, B.ITEM_DESC
    FROM   ITEM_LOC_SOH A INNER JOIN ITEM_MASTER B
    ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM
)
SELECT x.*, x.J12 + x.SPR + x.J16 + x.JS1 AS Totl
FROM   pivot_data
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(COALESCE(STOCK_ON_HAND, 0))
    FOR LOC
    IN  
    (
       15002 J12,
       16009 SPR,
       15008 J16,
       12002 JS1
    )
 ) x;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bf8b/7)

- Or, alternatively, you can project the total into the data before it is pivoted, by adding it as a union to `PIVOT_DATA` cte:

```
WITH PIVOT_DATA AS 
(
    SELECT A.ITEM, A.LOC, A.STOCK_ON_HAND, B.ITEM_DESC
    FROM   ITEM_LOC_SOH A INNER JOIN ITEM_MASTER B
           ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM
)
,
TOTALS AS
(
      -- Add Insert "Totals" rows to the Cte
    SELECT ITEM, 9999 AS Loc, SUM(STOCK_ON_HAND) AS STOCK_ON_HAND, ITEM_DESC
    FROM PIVOT_DATA
    GROUP BY Item, ITEM_DESC
)
SELECT x.*
FROM
(SELECT * FROM pivot_data
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM TOTALS
)
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(COALESCE(STOCK_ON_HAND, 0))
    FOR LOC
    IN  
    (
       15002 J12,
       16009 SPR,
       15008 J16,
       12002 JS1,
       9999 Total
    )
 ) x;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bf8b/13)

Comment: Hi StuartLC, I tried the first part of your solution. Its giving me an error of 'non constant expression is not allowed for pivot'

Comment: Apols, I missed the aliasing on the location values - I've fixed and added a fiddle. I've also changed the JOIN to an INNER join, instead of in the WHERE.

Comment: StuartLC, the query worked well with these columns.
When I add a few columns more, the total in the end is not coming correct. 
It's showing some very large value.

I have added the new code in the original post.

Comment: We can make the totals more robust in the second approach by doing the totals in another CTE which uses the first - this way we are guaranteed with working on the same data. I've updated + with a new fiddle.